# How to overlap edges of extended display

Tags: multiple-monitors

I am currently using windows 8.1 with two dell monitors in extended display mode.  I would like to extend certain applications across both monitors, but am running into issues where any content that would normally be in the center of the screen is split down the middle and difficult to understand. I understand this is proper behavior in this setup, but I was wondering whether anyone knew of an application or utility which would **allow multiple monitors to duplicate only certain portions of the screen**. To clarify, I would like a rectangular area around the center of my screen to appear on both monitors with different images on the opposing sides in a manner similar to how eyes overlap their fields of vision kind of like a ven-diagram.

I've attempted to use window's screen resolution gui to do this, but it forces the displays to either be entirely adjacent or entire duplicates.

Comment: what is the display adapter your using?  like in AMD the "eyefinity" setup of combining monitors as one virtual single allows for  "bezel" adjustments but mostly to make a continguous hole where the bezel would be. I have not found it to be very usefull for regular programs, just for video or games.  At any rate checking out to see how the GPU cards own software would handle things like this in thier special multi-display modes would be something to tests before realising how useless it can be ;-)